# Binding a collection to xamdatagrid on button click in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, infragistics, buttonclick, xamdatagrid

How to bind a collection to xamdatagrid on button click in wpf mvvm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML

```
   <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">Button</Button>
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
   ...
   configure columns to MyRowViewModel
   ...
   </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel

```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
     public ICommand ButtonCommand {get;set;}
     public ObservableCollection<MyRowViewModel> MyCollection {get;set;}
   }
```

and set in OnLoad:

```
   View.DataContext = viewModel;
```

and when command is called change your collection or create and wpf update your grid automatically